# Always load // protocol as http://, not file://

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, network-protocols

In my app, I load local files with the `file://` protocol in a `UIWebView`. I do however also load several `http://` protocol resources in those files, which in turn load other resources, but rather than using a specific protocol relying on the `//` protocol ([Protocol Relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)) to use the appropriate protocol, which should be either `http://` or `https://`, but which ends up being `file://`in my case.

I have been tinkering around this for a while now, trying to replace all `//` links with `http://` through javascript, unsuccessfully, and I'm pretty lost. I can't change the code that requests the `//` links, and iOS/Webkit automatically assumes that file:// is the right protocol to use.

Is there a way around this, making iOS always use `http://` in place of `//`, or any other way that would work?

Comment: You could try using a base element in your code to change the base URL, but the web view might ignore it as a security issue using a different scheme/domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking over it again, I realised I didn't really need to use the file-protocol at all – I simply get the HTML from the local file, input that into the `UIWebView` using `loadHTMLString: baseURL:`, and set the `baseURL` to `http://domain.com`. That way, the protocol used is HTTP.

This solution did involve quite some tinkering with the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and back/forward history changes, but it is nothing compared to trying to change the protocols.

If anyone has other solutions, I'm very interested to see them!

Comment: Actually, I'm still interested in the original question from this post, for different reasons though: Is there a way to make iOS always use http:// in place of //

Comment: @BAndonovski It's an interesting question, and as far as I'm aware, having a `baseURL` with the `http://`-protocol, all `//`-protocols are assumed to be `http://`. I'd suggest opening a new question if you need another solution though! :)